# passing array as function argument c

Tags: c, arrays, arguments

I currently send commands over spi as follows:

I want to create a function to send any command passed to it. Can I pass a byte array as an argument to function? Like I have below.

Comment: You cannot pass an array to/from a function in C. But you can pass a pointer to its first element.

Answer (score 2):

Passing arrays is done using pointers in C.
Since arrays may *decay* to pointers through an implicit conversion from `T[]` to `T*`, we pass a pointer to the function referring to the array.

Write the function like<sup>1</sup>

```
void sendCommand(uint8_t* Cmd) {
    ...
}
```

and call it like

```
sendCommand(SyncCmd);
```

**However**, watch out: `sizeof(Cmd)` yields the **size of the pointer, not the whole array**, when used within `sendCommand`. Therefore, you need to pass the size explicitly. See [this](https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/9/3/428) by Linus Torvalds to hear some harsh words on this matter.

---

<sup>1</sup> Note that `uint8_t[]`, `uint8_t*`, `uint8_t[42]`, and friends are all equivalent when used as parameters. That is, these are all equivalent:

```
void foo1(uint8_t*);
void foo2(uint8_t[]);
void foo3(uint8_t[42]);
```

<sub>Thanks to @Olaf for your contribution here.</sub>

Comment: `uint8_t cmd[]` works very well, too. It is more clear that is is use as an array internally - self-documenting code.

Comment: @Olaf Hmm, well, that's your perception. The fact that the pointer references an array should also be apparent when reading through the surrounding code. Also, what if someone really passed just one element as `cmd` with size 1? I prefer `uint8_t*`. But I'll mention their equivalence, yes. [Linus also has a say regarding this and the kernel](https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/9/3/499), only if you're interested.

Comment: I read Linus rant now. I fully agree with him that people should learn and know C. But that implies they are aware of the formal array argument conversion. They already have to know the actual array argument decays to a pointer, so the format argument decaying, too should be clear. If you rely on a specific size for an array argument, you have to pass that size (maybe the main problem is the `[]` syntax). Either as a constant or VLA. The function header should document the arguments ()inconjunction with e.g. Doxygen comments. Requiring reading the code to understand the interface is just bad